# How would I upload a zip file to the File Manager without unzipping it (need it to stay as a zip file)

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I need to upload zip files of logos, so that users can download the zipped file. These can't be unzipped (automatic with DNN) as that would create total chaos.

Tried uploading the zip file, it automatically decompresses.

Answer (score 1):

There is a checkbox at the top of file manager called "Decompress ZIP files" - make sure it is unchecked.